# Hyper-V's VM access web app which is hosted by the parent pc

Tags: web, client, virtual-machine, host, hyper-v

I was forced to use Hyper-V on my Windows 10 for some reasons: VMware is not compatible with Hyper-v but Hyper-V is required when developing c++ mobile app, or some other app I like; VMware make my windows 10 lag, not responding for a very long time after I pause my VMware's VM; ect,...

But when I have to use Hyper-V, I realize hyper-V can't transfer files between the parent pc (physical machine or I like to call PM) and virtual pc (Virtual machine or VM). I did figure a way to transfer files from my PM to VM: save the file of my PM as *.iso file and mount it to my VM, so my VM can open the disc and use the file.

Ok, now get to the point:

The bigger problem came when I need to get files (or just text) from my VM (virtual machine) to paste to my PM (physical machine). So I came up with the idea: create a web app (like Mvc) and run it locally on my PM, then let my VM access that web app through a web browser, then I can transfer files easily. Is it possible to do that? I got the web address http://localhost:11691/ when I run the web app on my PM, but when I paste the address to my VM, it just can't access.

Thank for reading :)

Comment: You have to connect via RDP...and all drives of the PM will be available in Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Windows 10, you can use PowerShell's copy item to transfer files between the host and virtual machine ([instructions here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/user_guide/vmsession#copy-files-with-new-pssession-and-copy-item)).  That's probably the easiest way to move files.

For older hosts/virtual machines, you can use the guest services integration component as well.  It isn't enabled by default so you'd have to enable it ([instructions to enable file copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/user_guide/managing_ics#enable-or-disable-integration-services-using-hyper-v-manager)).

And there is a shared clipboard if you use [enhanced session mode](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282274(v=ws.11).aspx).

And here is a [general reference for integration services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/reference/ic_info#hyper-v-guest-service-interface) :))

I'm working on the documentation for all of this, sorry for the highly scattered resources.

Comment: You are awesome, Shared clipboard seems promising, I see that enhanced session mode on Hyper-V host is already turned on by default, but how can I choose the local resource that you want to use? I can't find any way to pop up the "Connect to SomeVM" dialog like in the instruction, I can only click "Connect..." and the Virtual Machine popup.

Comment: I'm going with the first method (PowerShell) but when I type: $s = New-PSSession -VMName Windows 7 -Credential (Get-Credential) , a dialog pop up ask me to enter UserName, Password, I don't know how to fill those field. And I don't know how to find my VMId for the next command.

Comment: Virtual machines need to have an operating system installed in them -- they're basically just a blank partition that isolates a separate computer sharing hardware.  When you connect to a virtual machine, you should have a full OS with users etc.  The Username and password box should be a user in the virtual machine that you created when you installed the OS.

For shared clipboard -- literally the clipboard.  Try ctrl+C, ctrl+V.  Open the VM In VMConnect and log in/install an OS.

Answer (score 0):

There are two tools:
Windows Admin Center and HV Manager

The Windows Admin Center is more of a replacement for the Microsoft Management Console.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/windows-admin-center

And the HV manager is focused only on Hyper-V and distribution of vms
https://www.hv-manager.org/

These tools do their job well.
See details here: https://www.hv-manager.org/remote-access-to-hyper-v-through-a-browser/